# Omit comma value in copy activity in ADF (SQL Server to CSV) to get single column in sink file

Tags: sql-server, string, csv, character, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a CSV in ADLS using a copy activity from a SQL Server query, the problem is this string value contains a comma itself, what happens is when copying the CSV file, the file is copied with a new column, separated by the comma in the text cell, following the images.

[image]

This is the query that is being called for the source system in the copy activity

[image]

[image]

This is the file in the sink ADLS after the copy activity.

Is there a way we can escape the comma in the string format from the query source so a single column is assigned to the string including the comma?

Comment: If you must use images you could at least remove the unnecessary whitespace so we can see the question on one page.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this and got same output csv file in the Blob storage.

[image]

**But when I tested the source preview of dataset in the ADF It is showing as only in one column.**

As per my repro, only in the blob it is showing as two columns. In the blob it does not have any other alternate file extensions other than csv for this kind of files. That's why by default it may taking the column delimeter as comma(,).

There is nothing wrong in your approach and it is generating the correct result as per the preview of the dataset in ADF. you can continue with your pipeline.

If you want store the csv in blob, it will be stored like that only. When you want to use that file from blob in ADF, make sure you made the below changes to get the desired csv file.

[image]

If you set the Dataset **Column Delimiter other than Comma(,)**. you can get the result as single column.

**Or**

Change the **Escape Character from Backslash() to Double Quote(")**. You can see the desired result in the preview.

[image]